# Vaadin Flow Grid - sorting and inline filtering simultaneously

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid

I'm using a Vaadin Grid with sortable columns (lazy sorting on the backend side based on the QuerySortOrder).

[image: Sortable columns]

I would like to add inline filtering as well, but the sorting arrows are missing in the [example](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/grid#filtering) provided.

[image: Filters]

How can I add the sorting arrows? Vaadin version is 24.

**UPD:** I'm adding the example code as was requested in the comments. What component do I need to add explicitly to get the working sorting arrows?

```
grid.getHeaderRows().clear();
HeaderRow headerRow = grid.appendHeaderRow();

headerRow.getCell(nameColumn).setComponent(
        createFilterHeader("Name", personFilter::setFullName));
headerRow.getCell(emailColumn).setComponent(
        createFilterHeader("Email", personFilter::setEmail));
headerRow.getCell(professionColumn).setComponent(
        createFilterHeader("Profession", personFilter::setProfession));

...

private static Component createFilterHeader(String labelText,
        Consumer<String> filterChangeConsumer) {
    Label label = new Label(labelText);
    label.getStyle().set("padding-top", "var(--lumo-space-m)")
            .set("font-size", "var(--lumo-font-size-xs)");
    TextField textField = new TextField();
    textField.setValueChangeMode(ValueChangeMode.EAGER);
    textField.setClearButtonVisible(true);
    textField.addThemeVariants(TextFieldVariant.LUMO_SMALL);
    textField.setWidthFull();
    textField.getStyle().set("max-width", "100%");
    textField.addValueChangeListener(
            e -> filterChangeConsumer.accept(e.getValue()));
    VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout(label, textField);
    layout.getThemeList().clear();
    layout.getThemeList().add("spacing-xs");

    return layout;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the columns sortable?
https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/grid/#sorting-by-multiple-columns
-- Otherwise please add the code you have tried so we can improve on it.

Comment: Hi @cfrick, columns are already sortable and Vaadin shows sorting arrows if the header row is not modified. But in the filtering example header row is being removed and added in a customized way, so one needs to add sorting arrows explicitly. But I don't know how. I will add the code to the question.

Comment: From looking at the code, there should be means to make it work again,
especially if you are using a JVM language, that does not care for
protected or if you go with reflection). But my guess now is, that it
would be way easier to get what you want, if you would add the filter to
a second header column instead of replacing the one you like the way it
is.

Comment: I tried the second header row, but I can add it only on top of the existing one, but it doesn't look good. I didn't find a way how to add a second header under the first one.